# Measuring duty Cycle with XMEGA384C3

Tags: avr

I am using an XMEGA384C3 on an XPLAIN C3 Dev board. I'm using PC0 pin to measure duty cycle of a 60Hz 4VDC waveform around 45% duty cycle. The problem is I keep getting "0" or "1" for a duty cycle. I used a scope and I verified that the signal is getting to the pin.

I am using the exact code on [Atmel App Note 1306](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8045.pdf), except a slight modification to access the duty cycle variable in main from the ISR. The associated code is:

Tc_example.c (Main, has ISR and timer setup)

```
/* This file has been prepared for Doxygen automatic documentation generation.*/
/*! \file *********************************************************************
 *
 * \brief  XMEGA Timer/Counter example source file.
 *
 *      This file contains an example application that demonstrates the Timer/
 *      Counter driver.
 *
 * \par Application note:
 *      AVR1306: Using the XMEGA Timer/Counter
 *
 * \par Documentation
 *      For comprehensive code documentation, supported compilers, compiler
 *      settings and supported devices see readme.html
 *
 * \author
 *      Atmel Corporation: http://www.atmel.com \n
 *      Support email: avr@atmel.com
 *
 * $Revision: 1569 $
 * $Date: 2008-04-22 13:03:43 +0200 (ti, 22 apr 2008) $  \n
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Atmel Corporation All rights reserved.
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
#include <asf.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>
volatile static uint32_t currentDutyCycle;

/* Using XMEGA default clock of 2MHz */
#define F_CPU           2000000UL
#define CPU_PRESCALER   1

#include "avr_compiler.h"
#include "TC_driver.h"

/* Prototyping of functions. */

void Example3( void );



/* \brief This is the main function for executing one of the examples.
 *
 *  Uncomment one of the function calls to show the example.
 */
int main( void )
{
    PORTR_DIRSET |= PIN0_bm | PIN1_bm;
     Example3();


    do {
        /* Wait while interrupt measure Frequency and Duty cycle. */

        ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
        {
            //Display currentDutyCycle;

        }
    } while (1);


}
/*! \brief This example shows how to configure TCC0 for measurement of Frequency
 *         and Duty cycle of a signal applied to PC0.
 *
 *  This function implements example 3, "Using Input Capture to Calculate
 *  Frequency and Duty Cycle of a Signal" from the "Getting Started" section of
 *  application note AVR1306.
 */
void Example3( void )
{
    /* Configure PC0 for input, triggered on both edges. */
    PORTC.PIN0CTRL = PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc;
    PORTC.DIRCLR = 0x01;

    /* Select PC0 as input to event channel 0. */
    EVSYS.CH0MUX = EVSYS_CHMUX_PORTC_PIN0_gc;

    /* Configure TCC0 for Input Capture using event channel 2. */
    TC0_ConfigInputCapture( &TCC0, TC_EVSEL_CH0_gc );

    /* Enable Input "Capture or Compare" channel A. */
    TC0_EnableCCChannels( &TCC0, TC0_CCAEN_bm );

    /* Clear MSB of PER[H:L] to allow for propagation of edge polarity. */
    TC_SetPeriod( &TCC0, 0x7FFF );

    /* Start timer by selecting a clock source. */
    TC0_ConfigClockSource( &TCC0, TC_CLKSEL_DIV1_gc );

    /* Enable CCA interrupt. */
    TC0_SetCCAIntLevel( &TCC0, TC_CCAINTLVL_HI_gc);
    PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_HILVLEN_bm | PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm ;

    sei();


}
ISR(TCC0_CCA_vect)
{
    static uint32_t frequency;
    static uint16_t totalPeriod;
    static uint16_t highPeriod;

    uint16_t thisCapture = TC_GetCaptureA( &TCC0 );

    /*  Save total period based on rising edge and reset counter. */
    if ( thisCapture & 0x8000 ) {
        totalPeriod = thisCapture & 0x7FFF;
        TC_Restart( &TCC0 );
    }
     /* Calculate duty cycle based on time from reset and falling edge. */
    else {
        highPeriod = thisCapture;
    }

    currentDutyCycle = ( ( ( highPeriod * 100 ) / totalPeriod ) + currentDutyCycle) / 2;
    frequency = ( ( ( F_CPU / CPU_PRESCALER ) / totalPeriod ) + frequency ) / 2;

    PORTR_OUT ^= 1; // Toggle Led to make sure this ISR is actually executing

}
```

TC_Driver.c Atmel Timer Driver Appnote 1306:

```
/* This file has been prepared for Doxygen automatic documentation generation.*/
/*! \file *********************************************************************
 *
 * \brief  XMEGA Timer/Counter driver source file.
 *
 *      This file contains the function implementations the XMEGA Timer/Counter
 *      driver.
 *
 *      The driver is not intended for size and/or speed critical code, since
 *      most functions are just a few lines of code, and the function call
 *      overhead would decrease code performance. The driver is intended for
 *      rapid prototyping and documentation purposes for getting started with
 *      the XMEGA Timer/Counter module.
 *
 *      For size and/or speed critical code, it is recommended to copy the
 *      function contents directly into your application instead of making
 *      a function call.
 *
 *      Several functions use the following construct:
 *          "some_register = ... | (some_parameter ? SOME_BIT_bm : 0) | ..."
 *      Although the use of the ternary operator ( if ? then : else ) is discouraged,
 *      in some occasions the operator makes it possible to write pretty clean and
 *      neat code. In this driver, the construct is used to set or not set a
 *      configuration bit based on a boolean input parameter, such as
 *      the "some_parameter" in the example above.
 *
 * \par Application note:
 *      AVR1306: Using the XMEGA Timer/Counter
 *
 * \par Documentation
 *      For comprehensive code documentation, supported compilers, compiler
 *      settings and supported devices see readme.html
 *
 * \author
 *      Atmel Corporation: http://www.atmel.com \n
 *      Support email: avr@atmel.com
 *
 * $Revision: 1569 $
 * $Date: 2008-04-22 13:03:43 +0200 (ti, 22 apr 2008) $  \n
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Atmel Corporation All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 * and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. The name of ATMEL may not be used to endorse or promote products derived
 * from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY ATMEL "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE EXPRESSLY AND
 * SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL ATMEL BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF
 * THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *****************************************************************************/

#include "avr_compiler.h"
#include "TC_driver.h"

/*! \brief Configures clock source for the Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  This function clears the old clock source setting of the Timer/Counter and
 *  sets a new clock source according to the clockSelection parameter.
 *
 *  \param tc              Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param clockSelection  Timer/Counter clock source setting.
 */
void TC0_ConfigClockSource( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_CLKSEL_t clockSelection )
{
    tc->CTRLA = ( tc->CTRLA & ~TC0_CLKSEL_gm ) | clockSelection;
}

/*! \brief Configures clock source for the Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  This function clears the old clock source setting of the Timer/Counter and
 *  sets a new clock source according to the clockSelection parameter.
 *
 *  \param tc              Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param clockSelection  Timer/Counter clock source setting.
 */
void TC1_ConfigClockSource( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_CLKSEL_t clockSelection )
{
    tc->CTRLA = ( tc->CTRLA & ~TC1_CLKSEL_gm ) | clockSelection;
}


/*! \brief Configures the Waveform Generation Mode for the Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  This function clears the old WGM setting of the Timer/Counter and sets a
 *  new WGM setting according to the wgm parameter.
 *
 *  \param tc    Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param wgm   Waveform generation mode.
 */
void TC0_ConfigWGM( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_WGMODE_t wgm )
{
    tc->CTRLB = ( tc->CTRLB & ~TC0_WGMODE_gm ) | wgm;
}


/*! \brief Configures the Waveform Generation Mode for the Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  This function clears the old WGM setting of the Timer/Counter and sets a
 *  new WGM setting according to the wgm parameter.
 *
 *  \param tc    Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param wgm   Waveform generation mode.
 */
void TC1_ConfigWGM( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_WGMODE_t wgm )
{
    tc->CTRLB = ( tc->CTRLB & ~TC1_WGMODE_gm ) | wgm;
}


/*! \brief Configures the Timer/Counter 0 for input capture operation.
 *
 *  This function sets the Timer/Counter in input capture mode and selects
 *  the event lines that will trigger the individual input capture channels.
 *
 *  \note Output compare operation is disabled when input capture operation is
 *  enabled.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param eventSource      Event source selection.
 */
void TC0_ConfigInputCapture( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_EVSEL_t eventSource )
{
    tc->CTRLD = ( tc->CTRLD & ~( TC0_EVSEL_gm | TC0_EVACT_gm ) ) |
                eventSource |
                TC_EVACT_CAPT_gc;
}


/*! \brief Configures the Timer/Counter 1 for input capture operation.
 *
 *  This function sets the Timer/Counter in input capture mode and selects
 *  the event lines that will trigger the individual input capture channels.
 *
 *  \note Output compare operation is disabled when input capture operation is
 *  enabled.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param eventSource      Event source selection.
 */
void TC1_ConfigInputCapture( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_EVSEL_t eventSource )
{
    tc->CTRLD = ( tc->CTRLD & ~( TC1_EVSEL_gm | TC1_EVACT_gm ) ) |
                eventSource |
                TC_EVACT_CAPT_gc;
}


/*! \brief Enables compare/capture channels for Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  This function enables compare/capture channels according to the supplied
 *  enableMask. The enableMask can be obtained by ORing together the symbols
 *    - TC0_CCAEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCBEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCCEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCDEN_bm
 *
 *  Example: TC0_EnableCCChannels( &TCC0, TC0_CCAEN_bm | TC0_CCCEN_bm ) will
 *  enable channels A and C.
 *
 *  \note No capture/compare channels are disabled by calling this function.
 *  Disabling is done by calling \ref TC0_DisableCCChannels.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param enableMask       Mask of channels to enable.
 */
void TC0_EnableCCChannels( volatile TC0_t * tc, uint8_t enableMask )
{
    /* Make sure only CCxEN bits are set in enableMask. */
    enableMask &= ( TC0_CCAEN_bm | TC0_CCBEN_bm | TC0_CCCEN_bm | TC0_CCDEN_bm );

    /* Enable channels. */
    tc->CTRLB |= enableMask;
}

/*! \brief Enables compare/capture channels for Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  This function enables compare/capture channels according to the supplied
 *  enableMask. The enableMask can be obtained by ORing together the symbols
 *    - TC1_CCAEN_bm
 *    - TC1_CCBEN_bm
 *
 *  Example: TC1_EnableCCChannels( &TCC1, TC1_CCAEN_bm | TC1_CCBEN_bm ) will
 *  enable channels A and B.
 *
 *  \note No capture/compare channels are disabled by calling this function.
 *  Disabling is done by calling \ref TC1_DisableCCChannels.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param enableMask       Mask of channels to enable.
 */
void TC1_EnableCCChannels( volatile TC1_t * tc, uint8_t enableMask )
{
    /* Make sure only CCxEN bits are set in enableMask. */
    enableMask &= ( TC1_CCAEN_bm | TC1_CCBEN_bm );

    /* Enable channels. */
    tc->CTRLB |= enableMask;
}


/*! \brief Disables compare/capture channels on Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  This function disables compare/capture channels according to the supplied
 *  disableMask. The disableMask can be obtained by ORing together the symbols
 *    - TC0_CCAEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCBEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCCEN_bm
 *    - TC0_CCDEN_bm
 *
 *  Example: TC0_DisableCCChannels( &TCC0, TC0_CCAEN_bm | TC0_CCCEN_bm ) will
 *  disable channels A and C.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param disableMask      Mask of channels to disable.
 */
void TC0_DisableCCChannels( volatile TC0_t * tc, uint8_t disableMask )
{
    /* Make sure only CCxEN bits are set in disableMask. */
    disableMask &= ( TC0_CCAEN_bm | TC0_CCBEN_bm | TC0_CCCEN_bm | TC0_CCDEN_bm );

    /* Disable channels. */
    tc->CTRLB &= ~disableMask;
}


/*! \brief Disables compare/capture channels on Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  This function disables compare/capture channels according to the supplied
 *  disableMask. The disableMask can be obtained by ORing together the symbols
 *    - TC1_CCAEN_bm
 *    - TC1_CCBEN_bm
 *
 *  Example: TC1_DisableCCChannels( &TCC1, TC1_CCAEN_bm | TC1_CCBEN_bm ) will
 *  disable channels A and B.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param disableMask      Mask of channels to disable.
 */
void TC1_DisableCCChannels( volatile TC1_t * tc, uint8_t disableMask )
{
    /* Make sure only CCxEN bits are set in disableMask. */
    disableMask &= ( TC1_CCAEN_bm | TC1_CCBEN_bm );

    /* Disable channels. */
    tc->CTRLB &= ~disableMask;
}

/*! \brief Sets the overflow interrupt level.
 *
 *  This function sets the overflow interrupt level of this Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New overflow interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetOverflowIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_OVFINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLA = ( tc->INTCTRLA & ~TC0_OVFINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the overflow interrupt level.
 *
 *  This function sets the overflow interrupt level of this Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New overflow interrupt level.
 */
void TC1_SetOverflowIntLevel( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_OVFINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLA = ( tc->INTCTRLA & ~TC1_OVFINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the Error interrupt level.
 *
 *  This function sets the overflow interrupt level of this Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New error interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetErrorIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_ERRINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLA = ( tc->INTCTRLA & ~TC0_ERRINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the Error interrupt level.
 *
 *  This function sets the overflow interrupt level of this Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New error interrupt level.
 */
void TC1_SetErrorIntLevel( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_ERRINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLA = ( tc->INTCTRLA & ~TC1_ERRINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel A interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel A
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel A interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetCCAIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_CCAINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC0_CCAINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel A interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel A
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel A interrupt level.
 */
void TC1_SetCCAIntLevel( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_CCAINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC1_CCAINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel B interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel B
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel B interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetCCBIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_CCBINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC0_CCBINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel B interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel B
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel B interrupt level.
 */
void TC1_SetCCBIntLevel( volatile TC1_t * tc, TC_CCBINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC1_CCBINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel C interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel C
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel A interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetCCCIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_CCCINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC0_CCCINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel D interrupt.
 *
 *  This function sets the interrupt level for compare/capture channel D
 *  interrupt in Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  \param tc               Timer/Counter module instance.
 *  \param intLevel         New compare/capture channel A interrupt level.
 */
void TC0_SetCCDIntLevel( volatile TC0_t * tc, TC_CCDINTLVL_t intLevel )
{
    tc->INTCTRLB = ( tc->INTCTRLB & ~TC0_CCDINTLVL_gm ) | intLevel;
}


/*! \brief Resets the Timer/Counter 0.
 *
 *  This function will reset the Timer/Counter. After calling this function,
 *  the Timer/Counter will be in the same state as it would after a full
 *  reset of the device.
 *
 *  \param tc  Timer/Counter 0 module instance.
 */
void TC0_Reset( volatile TC0_t * tc )
{
    /* TC must be turned off before a Reset command. */
    tc->CTRLA = ( tc->CTRLA & ~TC0_CLKSEL_gm ) | TC_CLKSEL_OFF_gc;

    /* Issue Reset command. */
    tc->CTRLFSET = TC_CMD_RESET_gc;
}


/*! \brief Resets the Timer/Counter 1.
 *
 *  This function will reset the Timer/Counter. After calling this function,
 *  the Timer/Counter will be in the same state as it would after a full
 *  reset of the device.
 *
 *  \param tc  Timer/Counter 1 module instance.
 */
void TC1_Reset( volatile TC1_t * tc )
{
    /* TC must be turned off before a Reset command. */
    tc->CTRLA = ( tc->CTRLA & ~TC1_CLKSEL_gm ) | TC_CLKSEL_OFF_gc;

    /* Issue Reset command. */
    tc->CTRLFSET = TC_CMD_RESET_gc;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have your if...else in the ISR backwards, at least compared to AV1306 section 6.3

Comment: @BrendanSimpson Wow I did not notice that for hours... It seems to be working now! The frequency seems to be way off, but the duty cycle seems good. Edit: after 44% duty cycle it messes up

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @BrendanSimpson Seems to have an issue with the duty cycle being greater than 44%

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What does it do when duty is >44%?

Comment: @BrendanSimpson It reports something totally wrong like 10 or 14 for duty cycle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47779/discussion-between-zacharoni16-and-brendan-simpson).